# ReactJS image depend on the time

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image

i am trying to make a component on React JS for displaying different images depend on the time of the day, but i don't get why the image doesn't show up.

This is the code i made:

```
import React from 'react';
import image1 from "path";
import image2 from "path";

var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();`
var image;

if (hour < 20 && hour > 6) {
    image = { image1 };
} else {
    image = { image2 };
}

const Body = () => {
    return (
       <img src={image} alt="image" />
    );
};

export default Body;
```

I would really appreciate your help!!

Comment: Typo. You are wrapping the URLs assigned to `image1` and `image2` with **objects** when you assign values to `image` but `src` needs to be assigned URLs, not objects. Delete the extraneous `{` and `}`.

Comment: @Quentin your are right about the object part(and thank you very much) ,but  it still doesn't display the image,i tried a `console.log(image);` to  check  the path and it is not the same as the path i gave to the values `image1` and `image2`  so i  am guessing it has to do with react,i really don't know..

Comment: You aren't giving a *path* to `image1` and `image2`. You are importing an image (which will, presumably, be handled by  Webpack).

Answer (score 0):

This is how its done.If anyone ever needs it!

```
import React from 'react';
import image1 from "path";
import image2 from "path";

var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();`
var image;

if (hour < 20 && hour > 6) {
    image = image1 ;
} else {
    image =  image2 ;
}

const Body = () => {
    return (
       <img src={image} alt="image" />
    );
};

export default Body;
```